# C# Error converting null value to type double during deserialization

Tags: c#

Receiving this error message:

```
Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Double'. Path 'rings[0][0][3]', line 1, position 79.
```

The code producing the error:

```
string polygonGeom = geometry.ToJson();
GeoJSONClass.PolygonGeometry polygonGeometry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoJSONClass.PolygonGeometry>(polygonGeom);
```

why can it not Deserialize the JSON produced?

Comment: That's going to be very hard to answer without any information about the type involved. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment it is hard to answer without specific Type details. From the error it seems you are trying to map a value that can be null to a field declared as `double`.

Value types cannot be null. But if you need it to be null (maybe for optional fields) then use a `nullable value type`.

But since you are using an external type, make sure you handle the null values  before passing it to `sonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoJSONClass.PolygonGeometry>(polygonGeom);`